# Ошибка при установке lxml

Tags: python

Установил на *Windows 7* *python 3.4*.

Пробую установить модуль *lxml* командой `pip3 install lxml`.
Модуль начинает ставиться, но в итоге установка прерывается ошибкой:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)

Как это дело можно побороть?

Comment: Для 2.7 достаточно было поставить [это](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). Для 3.X скорее всего не поможет (не пробовал, может быть и хватит). Везде пишут, что [VS2010 Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-2010-express) достаточно поставить

Comment: Что делать в случае, если при попытке установить по третьему варианту пишет: "ERROR: lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."?

Comment: @VanoKi (переношу свой коммент из под удаленного ответа) Нужно смотреть что у вас за система, какая версия Python установлена, какая "битность" интерпретатора. Например (скорее всего), у вас может быть установлен 64-битный интерпретатор, а вы на него пытаетесь установить 32-битную сборку библиотеки (win32).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дело в том, что Python пытается скомпилировать исходники модуля. Для этого в Windows он пытается использовать компилятор Visual Studio.
Есть несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1. Установить Visual Studio (например, бесплатную Express Edition) и снова запустить установку через pip.
2. Скачать exe-файл отсюда https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/ и установить его как обычное приложение/библиотеку Windows.
3. Скачать whl-файл (wheel) и установить его с помощью команды:

   ```
   pip install путь_к_wheel_файлу.whl
   ```

Первый вариант наиболее предпочтителен, так как в следующий раз вам не потребуется искать в интернете бинарники или whl-файлы, а все будет сразу компилироваться

Также, есть большая коллекция бинарников и whl-файлов под Windows по этому адресу: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)